# c# winforms -Pass Parameter Between Modal Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a main form with `Purchase` button that opens a modal form with combo box and 2 buttons, `Confirm` and `Close`.

When I select the item and click `Confirm` it is automatically saved in the database.

What I want to do is when I hit `Close` button and return to the main form, the DataGridView must be refreshed only if I purchased at least 1 item.

Comment: This is a pretty vague/broad question unless you show us some specifics in code.

Comment: Just assign the form's DialogResult property with an appropriate value.  That closes the dialog and sets the return value of the ShowDialog() call.  Use DialogResult.Cancel if there isn't any point in getting the DGV refreshed.

Comment: Modal forms are confusing for beginners. Many assume that the form is gone forever when it is closed, whereas it is not the case, because it is just a class instance. The "DialogResult property" pattern reinforces confusion in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

To do something when the form is closed attach a handler to the `FormClosed` event, you can access whatever information you need from the form in its handler:

```
OtherForm other = new OtherForm();
other.FormClosed += (s, args) => 
{
    if(otherForm.SomeInformation == someValue)
        DoSomething(other.SomeData);
};
other.Show();
```

Comment: Could you illustrate your code please I can't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tima What about it don't you understand?  You attach a handler to this event, and then do whatever you want when the form is closed.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: I mean that (s, args)

Comment: @Tima They are the parameters for the event handler.  You shouldn't need to use either of them, they just need to be there.

Comment: your code has worked only when I changed the second += to => , did you mean it to be += or it was just a mistake ?

Comment: @Tima That was a typo, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I generally write a helper method on the modal form itself, like so:

```
public static ModalResponse ShowModal()
{
    OtherForm otherForm = new OtherForm();  
    otherForm.ShowDialog();
    //craft a ModalResponse based on the state of otherForm, and return it here
}
```

and invoke it like so in the parent Form:

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = OtherForm.ShowModal();
    //do things with the response
}
```

(`ModalResponse` is not a class that exists somewhere in the framework, it's just an example.)

The reason I favor this approach rather than just capturing the `DialogResult` is because `DialogResult` will (generally) only tell you what button was clicked. If you need more info about the state of the form input (as the OP mentioned), then a 'richer' object (richer than an `Enum` anyway) is needed.

Comment: I tried this and worked, thanks. I will also try the other replies for learning purposes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A Form is a class like many other and can contains properties.
The lifetime of a Form is not necessarily in sync with its visibility.

That's why you can set properties before the form is shown, change them in the code behind the modal form, then use them after the form has been closed.

```
// Create a instance of the modal form
using(var frm = new MyModalForm())
{
    // Initialize some properties
    frm.Text = "Product catalog";
    ...

    // Show the modal form. At this time, the code execution is suspended until
    // the modal form is closed
    frm.ShowDialog(this);

    // Once the form is closed, it remains instanciated and can still be used
    if (frm.RefreshRequired)
    {
        // Perform the datagrid refresh
    }
}

// At this time, the form is disposed because of the using block, and
// all the resources it used are cleaned

public class MyModalForm : ...
{
    ...
    public MyModalForm()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Set this flag to true or false according to the
    // operations done in the modal form
    // (in the event code of the buttons for example)

    public bool RefreshRequired = false;

    ...
}
```

Of course, the DialogResult property can be used, but this way allows many more properties to be retrieved, as the list of selected product for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the form's `DialogResult` to determine if close or canceled was clicked:

```
public class Modal : Form
{
    public Modal {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like

```
using (var modal = new Modal()) {
    modal.ShowDialog();
    if (modal.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
        // respond to confirm click here.
    }
    else if (modal.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) {
        // respond to cancel click here.
    }
}
```

The nice part is since you instantiated the `Modal`, you can still access its properties in your DialogResult checks. You're Modal class can set a property that specifies that at least one item was purchased and then check that property and respond in the else if where you know Cancel was clicked.